# What is the Purpose of c:\Users\Default\Documents folder?

Tags: windows

I need to move some files into the `Documents` folder of some users of our software.

On Windows machines, there is a folder `c:\Users\Default\Documents`.  What is the purpose of this folder?  Who can read/write to this folder?  I thought perhaps it was a "universal" documents folder, and anything there would show up for every other user, but I added a file and that didn't happen.

Comment: [Frome here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dbb36882-8552-4d18-af95-c73a9a40a0d3/what-are-the-default-and-public-folders-in-cusers-for?forum=w7itprogeneral) _Default User profile is a template profile for all created users. Whenever you create a new user profile, the profile is built based on the Default User profile.
The Public Folder is for sharing files with all other users that in the system, or on network. All local users can access this profile, but cannot access your private user profile._

Comment: That's the answer, @JohnnyMopp - post it as one and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Default User profile is a template profile for all created users. Whenever you create a new user profile, the profile is built based on the Default User profile.
>
> The Public Folder is for sharing files with all other users that in the system, or on network. All local users can access this profile, but cannot access your private user profile.

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dbb36882-8552-4d18-af95-c73a9a40a0d3/what-are-the-default-and-public-folders-in-cusers-for?forum=w7itprogeneral